# EXTJS: Whats the difference between Ext.widget and Ext.create?

Tags: extjs

I am new to EXTJS, sometimes very confused about those method calls. Can someone give some explaination?

Thank You!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Ext.widget` performs a very similar function to `Ext.create`. The main difference is that `Ext.widget` can only create components with an xtype. For example, these are equivalent calls:

```
const c1 = Ext.widget('panel'); // Uses xtype
const c2 = Ext.create('Ext.panel.Panel'); // Uses classname
```

Comment: Note that using xtypes for instantiating components - particularly if it's your own custom components - gives you greater flexibility to reorganise your code; you can move classes around without having to do large-scale changes.

Answer (score 1):

Ext.Widget ([docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/modern/Ext.Widget.html))

> Ext.Widget is a light-weight Component that consists of nothing more than a template Element that can be cloned to quickly and efficiently replicate many instances. Ext.Widget is typically not instantiated directly, because the default template is just a single element with no listeners. Instead Ext.Widget should be extended to create Widgets that have a useful markup structure and event listeners.

Another is when creating a class you can add

> alias: 'widget.somename'

Doing so now allows you to create objects

> Ext.create('widget.somename')

Or using it directly as

> xtype: 'somename'

Whereby Ext.create ([docs](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.0.0/modern/Ext.html#method-create))

> Instantiate a class by either full name, alias or alternate name.
>   If Ext.Loader is enabled and the class has not been defined yet, it will attempt to load the class via synchronous loading.

And a code example whereby all of it below produces the same results

```
 // xtype
 var window = Ext.create({
     xtype: 'window',
     width: 600,
     height: 800,
     ...
 });

 // alias
 var window = Ext.create('widget.window', {
     width: 600,
     height: 800,
     ...
 });

 // alternate name
 var window = Ext.create('Ext.Window', {
     width: 600,
     height: 800,
     ...
 });

 // full class name
 var window = Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
     width: 600,
     height: 800,
     ...
 });

 // single object with xclass property:
 var window = Ext.create({
     xclass: 'Ext.window.Window', // any valid value for 'name' (above)
     width: 600,
     height: 800,
     ...
 });
```

Comment: Question was about the factory method, Ext.widget, not about the class, Ext.Widget.